# Multiple aiohttp Application()'s running in the same process?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Can two `aiohttp.web.Application()` objects be running in the same process, e.g. on different ports?

I see a bunch of examples of aiohttp code like:

```
from aiohttp import web
app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/foo', foo_view, name='foo')
web.run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=10000)
```

I'm wondering if there's some equivalent where multiple `web.Applications()` can be configured to run at the same time. Something like:

```
from aiohttp import web
app1 = web.Application()
app1.router.add_get('/foo', foo_view, name='foo')
app2 = web.Application()
app2.router.add_get('/bar', bar_view, name='bar')
# This is the wishful thinking code:
web.configure_app(app1, host='0.0.0.0', port=10000)
web.configure_app(app2, host='0.0.0.0', port=10001)
web.run_apps()
```

My use case is that I have an existing python web framework that does this kind of thing, and I'm building a prototype that's analogous in python 3.6 with aiohttp.

I understand that multiple python servers can run behind e.g. nginx (see also http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html); that's not what I'm after. I want to explore the possibility of two aiohttp web servers with the same asyncio event loop, running in the same python process, serving on two different ports.

Comment: as of aiohttp 3.0, custom AppRunners might be another approach, see: https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_advanced.html#application-runners From the docs "For starting the application asynchronously or serving on multiple HOST/PORT AppRunner exists."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can - just write some wrapper with re-implementation of [`run_app`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/web.py#L412).

Here is a simple example. All app-specific parts of `run_app` are moved to the dedicated class `AppWrapper`. The `MultiApp` is responsible only for initialize all configured apps, keep running the loop and clean up.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


class AppWrapper:

    def __init__(self, aioapp, port, loop):
        self.port = port
        self.aioapp = aioapp
        self.loop = loop
        self.uris = []
        self.servers = []

    def initialize(self):
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.aioapp.startup())
        handler = self.aioapp.make_handler(loop=self.loop)

        server_creations, self.uris = web._make_server_creators(
            handler, loop=self.loop, ssl_context=None,
            host=None, port=self.port, path=None, sock=None,
            backlog=128)

        self.servers = self.loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(*server_creations, loop=self.loop)
        )

    def shutdown(self):
        server_closures = []
        for srv in self.servers:
            srv.close()
            server_closures.append(srv.wait_closed())
        self.loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(*server_closures, loop=self.loop))

        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.aioapp.shutdown())

    def cleanup(self):
         self.loop.run_until_complete(self.aioapp.cleanup())

    def show_info(self):
        print("======== Running on {} ========\n".format(', '.join(self.uris)))


class MultiApp:    

    def __init__(self, loop=None):
        self._apps = []
        self.user_supplied_loop = loop is not None
        if loop is None:
            self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        else:
            self.loop = loop

    def configure_app(self, app, port):
        app._set_loop(self.loop)
        self._apps.append(
            AppWrapper(app, port, self.loop)
        )

    def run_all(self):
        try:
            for app in self._apps:
                app.initialize()
            try:
                for app in self._apps:
                    app.show_info()
                print("(Press CTRL+C to quit)")
                self.loop.run_forever()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:  # pragma: no cover
                pass
            finally:
                for app in self._apps:
                    app.shutdown()
        finally:
            for app in self._apps:
                app.cleanup()

        if not self.user_supplied_loop:
            self.loop.close()
```

**Note**: be aware of the use of internal `aiohttp`'s method, that may be subject of change.

Now let's use it:

```
from aiohttp import web

async def handle1(request):
    return web.Response(text='SERVER 1')


async def handle2(request):
    return web.Response(text='SERVER 2')

app1 = web.Application()
app1.router.add_get('/', handle1)

app2 = web.Application()
app2.router.add_get('/', handle2)

ma = MultiApp()
ma.configure_app(app1, port=8081)
ma.configure_app(app2, port=8071)
ma.run_all()
```

As a side note, think again why you need this. In almost all cases the decoupling is the better choice. Setting many endpoints in the same process make them depend on each other. There's one case that comes to my mind and has "good" reasoning, the internal stats / debug endpoint.

Answer (score 14):

Looks like version 3.0 adds a better way to do this that wasn't available previously: https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_advanced.html#aiohttp-web-app-runners

**EDIT**

The documentation is (as pointed out), a bit unclear (I had to fight with it myself, too). To run multiple servers on multiple ports, just repeat the code from the documentation for each site. In short, you will need to create an Application, AppRunner (and call it's `setup()`), and a TCPSite (and call it's `start()`) for each separate Application/Server you want to run on a separate address/port.

Easiest way to do this is to create an async function for the repetitive site setup, and then can pass it your Application instance and a port. I also included the mentioned cleanup of the runners for when the loop exits.

Hope this helps.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web

runners = []

async def start_site(app, address='localhost', port=8080):
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    runners.append(runner)
    await runner.setup()
    site = web.TCPSite(runner, address, port)
    await site.start()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.create_task(start_site(web.Application()))
loop.create_task(start_site(web.Application(), port=8081))
loop.create_task(start_site(web.Application(), port=8082))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except:
    pass
finally:
    for runner in runners:
        loop.run_until_complete(runner.cleanup())
```

Comment: How would you make two different apps listen on two different ports? Your documentation link says it's possible, but the example only shows one.

Comment: @FrankT Updated the response with example code and additional explanation.

You're right, the documentation is a bit vague. In short, though, you basically just repeat the 4 lines of code for each server you want to run.

Hopefully the added example helps!

Answer (score 4):

Though the above answer has been accepted, here is an another approach:

Create test.py:

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio
import sys

@asyncio.coroutine
def status1(request):
    return web.json_response('App1 OK')

@asyncio.coroutine
def status2(request):
    return web.json_response('App2 OK')

def start():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        # App1
        app1 = web.Application()
        app1.router.add_get('/status', status1)
        handler1 = app1.make_handler()
        coroutine1 = loop.create_server(handler1, '0.0.0.0', 8081)
        server1 = loop.run_until_complete(coroutine1)
        address1, port1 = server1.sockets[0].getsockname()
        print('App1 started on http://{}:{}'.format(address1, port1))

        # App2
        app2 = web.Application()
        app2.router.add_get('/status', status2)
        handler2 = app2.make_handler()
        coroutine2 = loop.create_server(handler2, '0.0.0.0', 8082)
        server2 = loop.run_until_complete(coroutine2)
        address2, port2 = server2.sockets[0].getsockname()
        print('App2 started on http://{}:{}'.format(address2, port2))

        try:
            loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            server1.close()
            loop.run_until_complete(app1.shutdown())
            loop.run_until_complete(handler1.shutdown(60.0))
            loop.run_until_complete(handler1.finish_connections(1.0))
            loop.run_until_complete(app1.cleanup())

            server2.close()
            loop.run_until_complete(app2.shutdown())
            loop.run_until_complete(handler2.shutdown(60.0))
            loop.run_until_complete(handler2.finish_connections(1.0))
            loop.run_until_complete(app2.cleanup())

        loop.close()
    except Exception as e:
        sys.stderr.write('Error: ' + format(str(e)) + "\n")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

At terminal, open two tabs. In one tab, run

```
python test.py
```

In other tab, run

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8081/status
curl -X GET http://localhost:8082/status
```

You will get response

```
"App1 OK"
"App2 OK"
```